# Call to a member function select() on string

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hola estoy haciendo un programa en el cual estoy haciendo usuarios y roles, en el cual usuario va tener una relacion con rol para poder objetener el nombre del rol pero al momento de crear el controlador para hacer el index de user hago un join para la tabla rol y estoy usando dos modelos para el user que es el user eloquent en el cual ahi mando llamar los datos que tiene user al controlador mas aparte lo que tiene el rol pero me manda un error Call to a member function select() on string y esto es lo que tengo

```
el controlador

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\UserEloquent;
use App\Models\Rol;
use Session;
use Redirect;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index(){
        $tableUsers=UserEloquent::all()
        ->join('rol', 'users.rol_id', '=', 'rol.id')
        ->select('users.*', 'rol.nombre as categoria_rol') 
        ->get();
        
        return view("users.index",["tableUsers" => $tableUsers]);
        //return view
    }
```

Modelo User

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'role_id',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

User Eloquen

```
 class UserEloquent extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
    
        protected $table='users';
    
        protected $fillable=['name','email','password','role_id'];
    
        public function getRol()
        {
                                // Modelo de referencia, campo local, campo foráneo 
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Role','role_id','id');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Si trabajas con relaciones con Eloquent deberías hacer uso de `with()` para aprovechar al máximo esa funcionalidad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De primera instancia la consulta que construyes no es correcta justo en esta parte:

```
$tableUsers=UserEloquent::all()->join('rol', 'users.rol_id', '=', 'rol.id')
```

Te lo comento por que:

- El método `all()` que pertenece a la clase Model de Eloquent y como el propio código fuente indica y cito sirve para:

> Get all of the models from the database.

Luego entonces mezclarlos de esa forma no producirá la salida esperada

- De hecho si quitas a `get` de la jugada notarás como obtienes precisamente eso que te indica el error un *string* con un array de objetos con la data *recuperada* pero con la carencia de forma *natural* de acceso a los métodos tanto del builder de Eloquent como del builder de Database.

Entonces alcanza con removerlo de la consulta y dejarlo así:

```
$tableUsers = UserEloquent::join('rol', 'users.rol_id', '=', 'rol.id')
    ->select('users.*', 'rol.nombre as categoria_rol') 
    ->get();
```

**Enlaces**

- [Retornando modelos](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-models)
- [joins](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins)
- [Relaciones de Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#introduction)

Comentarios finales:

- Te recomendaría identificar tus entidades de forma adecuada, ya que noto 2 modelos destinados al User pero con la característica de que uno indica al inicio *Eloquent* lo cual no deja del todo claro el por que de su existencia
- Completa el ciclo de las relaciones ya que ahí solo noto el `belongsTo` y nos estaría quedando pendiente el `hasOne/hasMany` pues si usas las relaciones en algún momento las requeriras
- Esta consulta se resuelve muy fácil con *eager loading* recomiendo leas mucho al respecto